# How to build a Unity game without compressing C# scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a game where the player can edit the c# scripts as a mechanic but I'm not sure how to stop Unity from compressing the c# scripts into a dll file.

I've also spent a lot of time looking for a solution but have come up empty handed.

I tried looking through the Player Settings in the preferences but I found nothing. I also tried ChatGBT but it told me to turn off options that weren't there

Comment: C# code has to be compiled before it can be executed, and compiling it creates the DLL. There's no way to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @KenWhite is correct. You can't.